# Command line switch to start excel directly into new a new blank workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, command-line-arguments

When I start excel I get a welcome screen where I can pick a recent document, a new blank workbook, a new template, and other options. I would like to have Excel automatically just open a new blank workbook. For word, I can do this with

```
winword /w /q
```

to skip the splash screen and the welcome screen and open a blank document.

Is there an equivalent for excel?

```
excel /e
```

is close but it doesnt create a document.

Comment: "When I start excel I get a welcome screen ...", do you only open it from the command line? or is it onlly for this particular question?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio When I open an existing document, it takes me into the document directly without a welcome screen. Opening excel any other way (Start menu, terminal, explorer) all give me the welcome screen. I'm open to any method of doing it, I tried the terminal first b/c it works for word

Comment: If I understand you correctly, go to File -> Options. Disable `Show the Start screen when this application starts`. Press OK.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio amazing! can you post as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to File -> Options. Scroll down to the bottom.
2. Find `Show the Start screen when this application starts`, then uncheck/disable it.
3. Press <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]